# Reading system properties in Jboss from the UI

Tags: java, angularjs, jboss

If I make a java application, package it as a war, and deploy it to the Jboss container, I know I can read System Properties.

If I make a JavaScript (front end application), package it as a war, and deploy it to the JBoss container, I obviously cannot read the System Properties directly.

My question is:

Does JBoss expose a rest interface, or provide any other means of reading System properties by deployables that only contain a UI ( client code ) ?

I know I can combine server side and client side logic together ( make a rest service or even a servlet to return back System properties, once called by the UI ) An example of this can be found [here](http://javahonk.com/angularjs-read-system-property-jboss-server/) . However, I'd rather use a cleaner, built in solution, that is already implemented and supported.